# DropDownListFor why it gets the Key and Nothing else

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I have a property in my model very simple one:

[image]

Now this dropDown doesn't work right

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Camp, new SelectList(ViewBag.Camps, "Id", "Name"))
```

it returns `null` instead of a chosen Camp, but if I change that into:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Camp.Id, new SelectList(ViewBag.Camps, "Id", "Name"))
```

It would return me a `Camp` object with correct `Id`, but the `Name` would be still `null`.

Why?

**UPD:**

And now another problem is if I choose the second approach it would screw up with unobtrusive validation. Although I'll be able to get the right camp based on the chosen id.

Comment: Can you post the code in your controller where you're populating ViewBag.Camps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal. Only the `Id` is posted to the controller action. That's how dropdown inside forms work. So that's all you can hope to get there. You will then use this `Id` to get the corresponding Camp object from the database:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo([Bind(Prefix = "Camp")]int id)
{
    Camp camp = Repository.GetCamp(id);
    ...
}
```

Also please get rid of this `ViewBag` and use a real view model:

```
public class CampViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Camps { get; set; }
}
```

and in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new CampViewModel
    {
        Camps = Repository.GetCamps().Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.Id.ToString(),
            Text = x.Name
        })
    };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    Camp camp = Repository.GetCamp(id);
    ...
}
```

and the view:

```
@model CampViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.Id,
        new SelectList(Model.Camps, "Value", "Text")
    )
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Comment: The thing is in controller it returns ModelState invalid even after I found a camp based on a given Id and assigned that Camp object to the Model.

Comment: I added ModelState.Remove("Camp.Name") to the controller

Comment: Unobtrusive validation doesn't work. It doesn't get adorned with data-val-required attribute.

Comment: @Agzam, try making the Id property of the CampViewModel a nullable integer and decorate it with the Required attribute.